# Resonance Audio - progressive crackling / distortion on iOS

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, web-audio-api, resonance-audio

Reproduction url: https://lucaslcode.github.io/ios-web-audio-bug/

I am creating a web app that combines AFrame for augmented reality and Resonance Audio for spatial audio. Resonance uses the Web Audio api.

On iOS, the audio becomes progressively more crackly and distorted like a feedback loop, until it stops completely. I have tested this on an iPhone 6s running iOS 14.6 within about 10 seconds, and also occurs on an iPhone 12 mini on iOS 14.6 after a few minutes.

The issue does not occur on a Macbook Air (Early 2014, safari 14.0.1, macOS 10.14.6), windows 10 laptop or xiaomi phone running Chrome.

I would understand consistant glitching due to performance, but not gradually increasing.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

We saw similar behaviour in Safari on Mac when we were running animations with requestAudioFrame. We were starting more and more and not properly clearing the old ones. This caused the audio input to crackle more and more. Once we cleaned up the animations the audio problems went away.